# Plot a double integral

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I'm trying to plot the result of a double Integral

```
Plot[
   Integrate[Integrate[x^7 (x - 2)^4 (x - 3)^9, x], x]
   ,{x, -10, 10}
   ]
```

Results in a 22-degree polynomial, but **why doesn't the above Plot work?**

Can you update the Answer to state/explain why x=2 is not the point of inflection but x=0,3 are?

Comment: Use `Evaluate` or do  `p = Integrate[Integrate[x^7*(x - 2)^4*(x - 3)^9, x], x];
Plot[p, {x, -10, 10}]`  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcUCA.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
f[x_] = Integrate[Integrate[x^7 (x - 2)^4 (x - 3)^9, x], x]
```

Plot:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 2, 4.1}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now why doesn't this function have a point of inflection at 2? (only 0 and 3).  Could I have seen that just by looking at f" instead of plotting it? Even the 0 and 3 do not show from the plot, unless it's zoomed out a lot.

Comment: If you are going to make a function, you might consider making it immediate assignment instead of delayed, and then no need to do evaluate. As in `f[x_] = Integrate[Integrate[x^7 (x - 2)^4 (x - 3)^9, x], x];
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]` Only first time it will automatically evaluate the integral, but future calls will not.  Just another option. Both methods work the same way.

Comment: @E. Chan-López: See updated question plz